# Render element grouped by property object reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have json Array Like this:

```
{
   area:1,
   label: "element1"
},
{
   area:3,
   label: "element3"
},
{
   area:1,
   label: "element2"
},
{
   area:2,
   label: "element2_1"
}
```

I would render an element like:

Area 1 -
element1
element2

Area 2-
element2_1

Area 3 -
element3

I have done this for now, but now I don't know how to group for property "area"

```
this.state.areas.map(function(el, key){
        return (
          <div>
            <span><strong>{el.label}</strong></span>

          </div>

        );
)}
```

Comment: You will need to build a keyed structure (object) from your data.  Build and sort that before rendering to React.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your labels into an Array, you can group and render them like this.

```js
var Hello = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function() {
        this.state = {
            area: [
                {
                    area: 1,
                    label: ['element 1', 'element 2']
                },
                {
                    area: 2,
                    label: ['element 2_1']
                },
                {
                    area: 3,
                    label: ['element 3']
                }
            ]
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.state.area.map(function(el, key) {
                    return (
                       <div key={el.area}>
                          <span>
                              <strong>
                                { el.label.map(function(label) {
                                    return (
                                      <span key={label}>{label}</span>
                                    )
                                }) }
                              </strong>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                    );
                }) }
            </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello /> ,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can help you https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/69759/

```
const myState = [{
       area:1,
       label: "element1"
    },
    {
       area:3,
       label: "element3"
    },
    {
       area:1,
       label: "element2"
    },
    {
       area:2,
       label: "element2_1"
    }];

    const ShowArea = (props) => <div><strong>Area {props.area}</strong><span>{props.children}</span></div>

    const ShowLabel = (props) =>{
      return(<span style={{paddingLeft:'10px'}} key={props.label}><strong>{props.label}</strong></span>)
    };


    var Hello = React.createClass({

      render: function() {
          const CompareByArea = (a,b) => a.area > b.area;
          const OrderList = myState.sort(CompareByArea);
          let newState = {};
          OrderList.forEach(element=>{
              if(!newState[element.area])
                 newState[element.area] = [];
              newState[element.area].push({label: element.label});
          });

       const keys = Object.keys(newState);
       const Elements = keys.map((key) => <ShowArea key={key} area={key} > 
        {newState[key].map(ShowLabel)}
       </ShowArea>);

       return (<div>{Elements}</div>)
      }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Hello/>,document.getElementById('container')
    );
```

Comment: Hello gino, thankyou for your answer, As soon as I can I try your solution, and keep you updated :)